# $.Event is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an simple Javascript BOT.Its an simple js bookmarklet when clicked will create blogs in Blogger.com...I used Below code

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
document.getElementsByClassName('blogg-button GEE3RVNDMU')[0].click()
document.getElementById("newBlog-title").value ="hello blogger";
var node = document.getElementById("newBlog-address");
node.focus();
document.getElementById("newBlog-address").value ="hellosblogger";


setTimeout(function() {game();},1250);

function game()
{
var e = $.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 8});  
$("body").trigger(e);
}
```

Everything works perfect,But atlast I need to simulate Any keypress Event...So i used that in function game , But I get  **`$.Event` is not a function error** in Firexfox console . Please some one guide me or please tell any alternative to do an simple keypress event..It can be any key.

Comment: **1.2.6**? Why are you using a **five year old** version of jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

There really is no function named Event in the jquery library. To bind a event to jquery object, you can use Jquery.Bind which actually has the same syntax as the one you've used in your code.
So, to summarize:

```
$.bind("keydown",function(){})
```

For more info: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/t4sC6/) link.
All works without errors.
Maybe you should use latest version of `jQuery`.

Code:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.onload = game;
document.body.appendChild(script);

function game() {
    console.log($("body"));
    var e = $.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 8});  
    $("body").trigger(e);
}
```